# Make PHP socket_connect timeout

Tags: php, sockets, timeout, ping

I have a small application I created to analyze the network connection. It runs from a browser and connects to a local PHP/Apache server. It then asks PHP to send a ping packet through a raw socket. THe problem is that if the host I am trying to ping isn't alive or won't answer to pings, we never get an answer from the server.

I beleave the socket request lives until apache is restarted. I have been getting mixed results from my application lately and I am blaming apache using too many sockets. Currently I have set the AJAX call's timeout and I was happy with it. But I really need to make PHP do the timeouting so that I won't have 500,000 sockets open to an unreachable host.

Some sample code:

```
$sockconn = @socket_connect($socket, $target, null);
if(!$sockconn)
{
    $raw['error'] = socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
    $raw['status'] = false;
    return $raw;
}
```

This is the function that won't timeout. I need to get it to timeout. Also PHP script execution time DOES NOT affect sockets.

I am clueless.

Comment: Seriously, use [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/fsockopen) instead. It makes a lot of things a lot easier, it is more readily available (it is a core function that must be explicitly *disabled*, whereas the sockets extension must be explicitly *enabled*) and the 5th argument lets you define the connect timeout on a per-call basis.

Comment: @daverandom can I send ping packets through it to a host wothout a port? use RAW protocol?

Comment: @DaveRandom here is the code where I create the socket. Notice the AF_INET and SOCK_RAW: `        $socket = @socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1);
        if(!$socket)
        {
            $raw['error'] = socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
            $raw['status'] = false;
            return $raw;
        }`

Comment: In *theory* yes (although with the more advanced `stream_socket_*` functions rather than `fsockopen()`). In practice it would be a massive PITA. I sort of assumed you would be dealing with TCP, most of the time that's what people are doing. If what you want is a PHP-driven ICMP echo implementation, though, I've already done that... take a look at this: http://download.networkm.net/code/php/class.ping.1.0.tar.gz (note that it was written for PHP4, and when my OO skills left... something to be desired, but it does work I have used it a couple of times)

Comment: Oh plus there's a whole bunch of random debugging crap left in there. Just remove lines 291-296

Comment: @DaveRandom Thank you, I'll take a look at your class!

Comment: New! Improved! Generally easier to use and not quite as crap! http://download.networkm.net/code/php/class.ping.2.0.tar.gz

Comment: @DaveRandom Thank you. The class works wonders!! May I use it in my network analyzer project?

Comment: Licensed under LGPL, and to sum up that basically means "Yes, you can use it for whatever you like" :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set timeouts for reading and sending using the following [options](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-get-option.php):

```
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => 1, 'usec' => 0));
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec' => 1, 'usec' => 0));
```

Alternatively, you can use [non-blocking sockets](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-nonblock.php) and periodically poll the socket to see if the remote host responded.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [default_socket_timeout](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout).