# socket_connect does not timeout

Tags: php, sockets, timeout

I am using sockets to send data to a server that may not be responding. So I am trying to define a timeout by using this solution in SO.

[Make PHP socket_connect timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881708/make-php-socket-connect-timeout)

```
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => 1, 'usec' => 0));
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec' => 1, 'usec' => 0));
```

This works when the connection is made and the server takes too long to respond.
But when it can't create a connection `socket_connect($socket, $addr, $port);` the timeout is about 20 seconds.

Why is this 20 second timeout happening and how can I force the connection creation to timeout after 1 second too?

Comment: usec are microseconds why did you set it to 0?

Comment: @RobertPodwika because I want it to be exacly 1 second and 0 microseconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by switching to a non-blocking socket, looping until either a connection is gained or a timeout was reached, then back to blocking again.

```
// an unreachable address
$host = '10.0.0.1';
$port = 50000;
$timeout = 2;

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

// switch to non-blocking
socket_set_nonblock($sock);

// store the current time
$time = time();

// loop until a connection is gained or timeout reached
while (!@socket_connect($sock, $host, $port)) {
    $err = socket_last_error($sock);

    // success!
    if($err === 56) {
        print('connected ok');
        break;
    }

    // if timeout reaches then call exit();
    if ((time() - $time) >= $timeout) {

        socket_close($sock);
        print('timeout reached!');
        exit();
    }

    // sleep for a bit
    usleep(250000);
}

// re-block the socket if needed
socket_set_block($sock);
```

edit: see @letiagoalves answer for an neater solution if you are using sockets created with fsockopen() or stream_socket_client()

Comment: +1 thanks. I used a different mechanism. it was easy to change. see my answer

Answer (score 2):

I changed my socket communication mechanism to use `stream_socket_client ($remote_socket, &$errno, &$errstr, $timeout)` function instead. This function allows to define the connect timeout unlike `socket_connect ($socket, $address, $port)` which doesn't.

To force a timeout using `socket_connect` see @bigtallbill answer.

Comment: That is definitely a lot neater :P
Though it does return a file resource instead of a socket rescource, so use-case is definitely something to consider. I'm not fluent enough with socket internals say whether using either method is better.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of variants with sockets..

[**fsockopen**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) the best for simple operations, ex. testing connections

Answer (score 0):

The SO_RCVTIMEO/SO_SNDTIMEO options don't work for socket_connect on some platforms, but only for socket_recv/socket_send. I can see it works on Ubuntu, but not Mac OSX.