# PHP - how to reduce a timeout connection SOCKET

Tags: php, sockets, timeout

I'm making a request for a socket but when it's offline socket_connect takes around 60s to inform me time out, is there any way I do not have to wait all this time when it's offline?

Sorry for the grammar. I'm using a translator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make PHP socket\_connect timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881708/make-php-socket-connect-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the time it waits for the connection to establish:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 10);
```

for a 10 second timeout.

Or you can set it in php.ini.

Comment: i change on php ini to set 

; Default timeout for socket based streams (seconds)
; http://php.net/default-socket-timeout
default_socket_timeout = 5
and i add on code
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5);

Even more in execution it tries 60s with the socket

Comment: That is probably because it cant connect. The a timeout wont work. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689932/socket-connect-does-not-timeout for a non-blocking socket connection with a timeout